# query with group by count and also brings count of all record in ad table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In below query it brings count number of ad in each mastercategory. I also want one additional column that brings count of all ad (sum of all ads regardless of which master category). What changes I need to bring about in below query?

Thanks

```
select count(*),master_category,count(a2.adid) from ad a1
inner join Category c on a1.catid=c.id
inner join ad a2 on a1.adid=a2.adid
group by c.master_category
```

Comment: Where do you want to see the total. Can you shoe us expected results?

Comment: @SeaSharp just one extra column with same value thats total value

Comment: Why are you joining to `ad` twice?  It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want add  a column with the total count you could use a cross join between the result by categories  and the total count

```
    select  t1.master_category, t1.count_by_cat, t2.tot_count
    from  (
    select  master_category,count(a2.adid) count_by_cat 
    from ad a1
    inner join Category c on a1.catid=c.id
    inner join ad a2 on a1.adid=a2.adid
    group by c.master_category )
    ) t1
    cross join  (
        select count(*) tot_count
        inner join Category c on a1.catid=c.id
        inner join ad a2 on a1.adid=a2.adid
    ) t2
```

A cross join is a cartesian product between two set of rows .. in this case one set is for the categories result and the second in just one rows

then the use of cross join with the total result allow to show for each row the same result  .. (in this case the total value calculated  by the second  subquery)
Pratically is a join between the result for each row for category and a single value

Comment: its not compiling

Comment: can you please explain how cross join fits like a gloove

Comment: why u use inner joins inside cross join, results are same?

Comment: The use of inner join inside a subquery id for  build the relation you need .. once you have this relation (this set of rows) the subquery select the  total count  ..  this subquery return just the total count  .. you must think at each subquery as  a separated  query  ... assembled by the outer select  ..  using join

Comment: give me cases where the results will be different with and without the cross join's inner joins and a2

Comment: You should think in term of set of datas ..  you have the same set of data  but over this set you want perform two different level of aggregation  one groupd  by  category and the secondo without group by.. so  in my code in each subqiery the join condition is the same  ..  but le level of aggreagtion is different  ..  once obtained  these tow result .. th external oart of the query select the result  ..

Comment: You comment for the sample  "give me cases where the resul  .. " have not sense ...  if you want the result you are looking for then the  join condition  in subquery must be the same  ... only the aggreagtion  level is different

Comment: for this query   ..  just think at the different aggregation level between the two query  .. (the join must be the same) and cross join is jus a cartesain product builder  ..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select c.master_category, 
       count(a1.adid) as countGroup, 
       min(a2.count1) as countAll
from ad a1
inner join Category c on a1.catid=c.id
left join (select count(ad.someColumn) as count1 from ad) as a2 on a2.adid = a1.adai
group by c.master_category
```

Comment: its not compiling

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select c.master_category, count(*) as category_cnt,
       sum(count(*)) over () as total_cnt
from ad a inner join
     Category c
     on a.catid = c.id
group by c.master_category;
```

I don't understand why you are joining to `ad` twice.  This should not only be the simplest approach, but it should have the best performance for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

**I just modify your query, hope this will help you**

```
select count(
    select * from ad a1
    inner join Category c on a1.catid=c.id
    inner join ad a2 on a1.adid=a2.adid) as Total,master_category,count(a2.adid) from ad a1
    inner join Category c on a1.catid=c.id
    inner join ad a2 on a1.adid=a2.adid
    group by c.master_category
```